Dynamically Loading Multiple Remote Angular Modules using Module Federation
I'm working on migrating an Angular application that previously loaded additional modules using script tags in the index.html to leverage Module Federation for a microfrontend architecture.
My challenge:
I have a main module (PortX) that serves as the shell application.
Upon loading PortX, I need to dynamically load two additional Angular modules (port a and port b) hosted on separate ports. In my previous setup, I achieved this by adding script tags for each module directly in the index.html.
Question:
How can I achieve this dynamic loading behavior using Module Federation in Angular?
Are there recommended approaches for handling dependencies between these modules.
